# Easy way to match DB column names to json keys?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

So I have a very simple json object that represents a DB row entry and I need to save it as such. So for example json has

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

and in my database I have a table with columns id, name, price and tags. What is the easiest way to do this besides doing

```
$mysqlObject->id = $jsonObject->id;
$mysqlObject->name = $jsonObject->name;
$mysqlObject->price = $jsonObject->price;
$mysqlObject->tags = $jsonObject->tags;
$mysqlObject->save();
```

The above will work but in my particular example I have 200-300 columns and typing that all out would take forever.

Comment: [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) in a loop, probably.

Comment: "tags" should be stored in a separate table.

Comment: Considering that you have such a huge amount of columns, it seems that a [Document oriented database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) might be a much better choice of storage than RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the column names in a list and iterate over it.

```
$column_names = Array(...);
foreach($column_names as $col_name) {
    $mysqlObject->$col_name = $jsonObject->$col_name;
}
$mysqlObject->save();
```

That should do the trick. Make sure to have a hard-coded list on the server-side and not rely on the JSON or the script will be open to injection attacks.

Comment: I think the problem was that the OP doesn't want to type out all the names since there are 200-300 of them.

Comment: Sure, that can be solved in a multitude of ways, not necessarily programmatic.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
$mysqlObject = MysqlModel::create(json_decode($jsonObject));
```

Of course you need to create an Eloquent model for this. And you can have the benefit of the `Mutator` of the Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `fill`

```
$mysqlObject->fill((array) $jsonObject);
```

If you can decode the json string as an array, that would be preferable.  If you are using `json_decode`, pass `true` as the second argument.  That way you don't need to cast the json object to an array before passing it into the `fill` function.